# In jquery how to concat variable

Tags: jquery, ipad, drag-and-drop

```
window.onload = function(){

    $('.content').bind({click:function(){

        var len = $('.main').children().length;
        var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("id"+$(this).attr('id'));  
        var draggable = new webkit_draggable('+id1+',{revert : true  });

}});}
```

in above code if i passed value of id directly then it's working properly but if I tried for passing value via variable then it's not working I am not sure about how to pass value of id1 in var draggable. The value should be in couts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new webkit_draggable(id1,{revert : true  });
```

if you want pass as quote

```
new webkit_draggable(''+ id1 +'',{revert : true  });
```

or you can use

```
new webkit_draggable(id1.toString() ,{revert : true  });
```

Comment: @Pranali Rewdekar see how can you passed as quote